# How this anti-bot defence works?

Tags: security, web-scraping, bots

I tried loading a few pages from https://property24.com with Selenium & Chrome/Firefox.
I have got instant block after downloading single page.

Now I see this [image]
Any ideas what service they use?

Comment: I have just tried use proxy to download a page manualy (without Selenuim). I got blocked. It was not free proxy, it was dedicated proxy i.e. this proxy used only by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that curl works fine with it.